# Magento Help: If current parent ID = x, show this content

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

Need some help with a Magento php script....

I want do write an if statement that  basically says "If the current category's parent ID = x, show this block of html".

I've figured out how to write this if statement for the current category, but not the current PARENT category... here's the code for that:

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current _category')->getId() == 11) : ?>
    //html here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Really appreciate any help you can give me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <?php 
        $cat = Mage::registry('current_category'); 
        $parentCat = $cat->getParentCategory();
        if ( $cat && $parentCat && $parentCat->getId() == 11) : ?>

        //html here

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Works like a CHARM. Seriously appreciate it!